# log connection attempts from an IP blocked by iptables

Tags: centos, iptables

I blocked an abusive IP from a CentOS server using `iptables`, dropping all connection attempts on all services / ports.

As is the way of things, the server with this IP may have been part of a botnet, and may have been cleaned in the time since I blocked it. I would like to find out if it's still trying to attack the server, so I can decide whether to unblock the IP... without unblocking it first.

I have tried searching through /var/log for anything that looks like `iptables`, grepped /var/log/secure for the offending IP, but have turned up nothing.

Is there a log of dropped connection attempts for `iptables`, or a way to configure the rule to log attempts but still drop them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, `iptables -v -L` lists the counts of packets and bytes that traverse a given rule, so you can see how much traffic you're dropping, and I wouldn't be too hard to write a tool that parses and reports that info.

Comment: good point - I was able to check this now, without modifying any rules, by running the command once and then again after 30 minutes and comparing the traffic - no increase means no further attempts have been made in that timeframe. All the answers here are great though, thanks to all. I've changed this to the accepted answer as this was what I used to solve the problem, the others are still valid.

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly log the packets, using the `LOG` target. You'd add a rule in your chains with the same criteria as the `DROP` rule for the abusive IP, but using `-j LOG` instead of `-j DROP`.

In addition you can specify the log prefix using `--log-prefix`, and a log level using `--log-level`. It's also common to specify rate limits to avoid flooding the logs... See [the iptables documentation](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.4) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set up a logging chain for your dropped packets. There is a good tutorial on doing that at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/ which boils down to adding something similar to the following to your current ruleset:

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```